# NSString Prevents Webview from Loading

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, webview, nsstring

I have a strange issue that I have not yet been able to figure out. I have a web view that loads with three variables. The page loads fine if I do not include the userId. But when I do include the userId, it does not work.

Strangely, if I manually userId to a value like @"150", then it works fine. could the problem come from the fact that the value for userId is a number? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
NSString *userId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"userId"];

NSString *finalLat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                    stringForKey:@"latitudeString"];

NSString *finalLon = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                    stringForKey:@"longitudeString"];

timerFirst = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/page.php?lat=%@&lon=%@&user_id=%@",finalLat, finalLon, userId];
[webViewFirst loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]]];
```

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint after you create userId to check its value ?

Comment: I haven't placed a breakpoint, but I have setup an alert that displays the value and it seems to be working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to place a breakpoint just before you launch *loadRequest*, and check your NSString *link* ?

Comment: Check userId,finalLat,finalLon has value if not then i think u forget to [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize] when ever u set String in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Make sure loading in NSStimer is not blocking your request in UIWebview

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want `repeats:YES` ? I assume that `@selector(loading)` calling some kind of VC creation and you doing it evey 0.5 sec. Check it, this may causing some issue here. But i'm just guessing - this is not enough code to answer this question.